# How best to TDD generics?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, tdd

Let's say I'm developing a database application and I have a number of entity classes i.e. Customer, Order, Product etc. I want to develop repositories for these (both real and mocked) but I don't want to duplicate code so I create a base Entity class and and a Repository generic containing my CRUD code. My question is, in "proper" TDD environment how would I go about developing this?

My first instinct is to start with one entity (e.g. Customer) and go through the TDD cycle for each CRUD task, then when I've got most of it written start with another entity and so on. However, if I've designed my architecture properly then I'll have working CRUD support for all my other entities long before I've written tests for them. My impression of "good" TDD is that you only ever write tests that fail and then for each test only write code to make it pass.

Is it bad form to test only a single entity for the generic portion of their implementation? How are generics typically developed with TDD?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have Customer:Entity ,Order:Entity and etc, and genereic repository IRepositry<T> where T:Entity ?

Comment: I think I would create a couple of the classes without the base class, creating tests as I go. Then I would follow Red, Green, Refactor and introduce the base class as a refactor step. Making sure the original tests continue to succeed.

Comment: Frank: yep, that's exactly what I'm doing to save code duplication.

Comment: Jras: that's precisely what I did, and then I created my base Entity class and then my repository classes from that. My question is: should I now duplicate all my tests and test each instantiation of that repository generic for each entity that uses it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In previous project we have done the following:

- Start with one entity and implement a repository for it using TDD
- Add another entity + repository using temporarily copy pasted tests
- You now have duplication between your two entities and your two repositories, but green tests
- Do a refactoring to extract an entity base class and make sure all tests pass
- Do another refactoring to extract a generic repository implementation referencing the entity base class, and once again make sure all tests pass
- You now have all passing tests and a generic repository, but duplication in the tests

You now have a choice:

- Remove the temporarily copy pasted tests from the test class for one of the entities but leave the tests for the other

or

- Extract a super class for the test classes which contains the tests for the generic repository, so that they run once for each entity type. I.e. if you have a test for `SelectById` that test runs once for each entity type, just by inheriting from a common base class.

If you use the second approach you know that you have working mapping/CRUD operations for all entities, but the test suite takes a little longer to execute.

Comment: 2d approach (test superclass) I would only use if the Repository's behavior is not uniform across all implementations, i.e. some of its methods are abstract or templated. I've rarely seen this case, usually the methods you define on a base Repository class are pretty much Entity type-agnostic.

Comment: It would be a good approach to test different types of repositories such as NHibernateRepository, InMemoryRepository, etc. though.

Comment: @guillaume31 Yes, the benefit comes from running the tests against the mapping/tables etc for each specific entity. Let's say you have renamed a property in EntityB so that the mapping is broken. If you only run tests using EntityA you would not find that problem. However, you might want to consider only running a subset of the generic repository tests for each entity type.

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes perfect sense, the idea of templating the test classes as well simply didn't occur to me. Having thought about it a bit more I would argue that testing each version of the generic does in fact make sense, particularly in the case of nHibernate where entity properties are virtual. While the behaviour may initially be uniform across all repositories there's nothing to stop someone coming along at a later date and overriding methods in a way that breaks that expected uniformity. Full unit testing across all generic'd classes would help detect bugs caused by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "proper" TDD environment. There are many possible styles for the red-green-refactor process itself, and TDD doesn't define a recipe as to how you should combine these small cycles to attain a fully implemented system.

In your case, I guess you could either implement 2 Repositories consecutively, realize there's duplicate code and refactor to genericity, keeping the existing tests as a test harness. Or, go for a generic Repository constrained on the `Entity` type right from the start. You can use a fake subclass of `Entity` in your tests as long as the Repository doesn't rely on Entity-specific behavior.